# Showing that $cf: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^*$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, continuity

$\newcommand{\scrF}{\mathscr{F}} \newcommand{\scrO}{\mathscr{O}} \newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}} \newcommand{\scrM}{\mathscr{M}}$
**Proposition:** Let $(\Omega, \scrF)$ be a measurable space and $f:\Omega \rightarrow \R^*$ be a measurable function where $\R^*$ denotes the extended real line. Then for any $c \in \R$ the map $cf:\Omega \rightarrow \R^*$ is also measurable.

I was told that to solve this problem I should first show that $F(x) = cx$ is continuous on $\R^*$ and then the result is immediate. Here are some pertinent definitions.

> **Definitions:**
>
> 1. The extended real line $\R^*$ is a topological space with topology $\scrO^*$ being the minimal topology containing all basic open sets in $\R^*$; i.e sets of the form $[-\infty, a), (a,b)$ and $(b,\infty]$.
> 2. The topological space $(\R^*, \scrO^*)$ is *first countable*. This means that for any $x \in \R^*$ there exists a sequence of open sets $(O_n(x))$, each containing $x$, such that for any open set $U \in \scrO^*$ containing $x$ there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $O_N(x) \subseteq U$.
> 3. The topological space $(\R^*, \scrO^*)$ is also Hausdorff, and so showing that a map is continuous on $\R^*$ is equivalent to showing that $F$ is sequentially continuous.
> 4. If $(X, \scrM)$ is a topological space, we say that a sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x \in X$ if for every open set $U \in \scrM$ containing $x$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$ one has the $x_n \in U$.

I know that in order to show that an arbitrary map $f:\Omega \rightarrow \R^*$ is measurable it is sufficient to show that for any open set $O \in \scrO^*$ we have that $f^{-1}[O] \in \scrF$, so I understand that once I've shown that $F = cx$ is continuous on $\R^*$ then I will have that $cf$ is measurable. This would be because $cf = F \circ f$ and then if $O$ is any open set in $\scrO^*$ then $cf^{-1}[O] = f^{-1}[F^{-1}[O]]$ and since $F$ is continuous the preimage of an open sets is open; i.e $F^{-1}[O] \in \scrO^*$ and then since $f$ is measurable $f^{-1}[F^{-1}[O]] \in \scrF$ as required.

The issue I'm having is actually showing that $F$ is continuous. I'm trying to approach it by showing that $F$ is sequentially continuous, because this is equivalent since $(\R^*, \scrO^*)$ is Hausdorff. So I would like to show that if $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $\R^*$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$ then $F(x_n) \rightarrow F(x)$. I don't have so much an attempt as I do a bunch of ingredients I can't seem to make work together.

*Scratch:* Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $\R^*$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$. Assume that $O$ is an open set in $\scrO^*$ which contains the point $F(x) = cx$. Because $\R^*$ is first countable, there exists a sequence of open sets $(U_n)$ each containing $cx$ such that for $N \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $U_n \subseteq O$.

I can't seem to be able to close this off, I'm not used to showing working in topological spaces so maybe that's part of the issue. Moreover do I need to distinguish the cases where $F(x) = \infty$ or $F(x) = -\infty$? Maybe these are really the cases that are supposed to be more important for this problem. Thanks in advance for the help and let me know if there are any clarifications I can make to help the readability of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is whether the function $F:\mathbb{R}^*\to\mathbb{R}^*, x \mapsto cx$ is continuous, then the answer is yes.

Notice that, as a function on $\mathbb{R}$, $F$ is continuous in the $\delta,\epsilon$ sense, and one can prove that a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ is continuous in the $\delta,\epsilon$ sense if and only if it is continuos in the "abstract topological sense" (i.e. $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for every open set $U$). Therefore, we could almost already conclude that F is continuous on its extended domain...

Anyway, we shall prove it directly with the definition (preimage of open set is open). Having defined $F$ on $\mathbb{R}^*$ as above with $F(+\infty)=+\infty$ and $F(-\infty)=-\infty$ (assuming $c>0$... but for negative values of $c$ the reasoning is exactly the same), we have:
$$F^{-1}((a,b))=\Bigl(\frac{a}{c},\frac{b}{c}\Bigr)$$
for every open interval $(a,b)$ and
$$F^{-1}([-\infty,b))=[-\infty,\frac{b}{c}\Bigr), \qquad F^{-1}((a, +\infty])=\Bigl(\frac{a}{c},+\infty]$$

Now, since the subsets of the form $(a,b)$, $[-\infty,b)$ and $(a, +\infty]$ form a basis for the topology on $\mathbb{R}^*$, this suffices* to show that $F$ is continuos and (immediate consequence) measurable.

---

(*) More precisely, it is sufficient (as we have done) to check that the preimage of an open set *of that form* is open. Then, since every other open set is a union of sets of that form (definition of basis for a topology), continuity is proven.